# Labeled Number Line

Tags: diagrams

I am transferring a professor's .doc files to LaTeX so that we can do more sophisticated formatting and I ran across a problem.

I would like to recreate this number line in LaTeX.

[image: number line]

Help with which package to use and which commands to study would be a great help.

Comment: see this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45006/how-to-plot-intervals-and-points-in-the-real-line

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); the manual is great and contains numerous examples; in the following example, the basic constructs are `\node` and `\draw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% a straight line segment
\draw (0.5,0) -- (10.5,0);
% the ticks and their labels
\foreach \x  in {1,...,10}
  \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below,fill=white] {\the\numexpr\x +112\relax};
% the thicker segment
\draw[ultra thick] (2.06,0) -- (8.94,0);
% the labels
\node[fill=white,draw=black,circle,inner sep=2pt,label=above:{$L_1=114.06$}] at (2.12,0) {};
\node[fill=white,draw=black,circle,inner sep=2pt,label=above:{$L_1=119.94$}] at (8.9,0) {};
\node at (5.5,-0.8) {$\mu$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's a variation using [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) (which internally uses `TikZ` and is very useful for plots):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis y line=none,
  axis lines=left,
  axis line style={-},
  xmin=112.5,
  xmax=121.5,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
  xlabel=$\mu$,
  scatter/classes={o={mark=*}},
  restrict y to domain=0:1,
  xtick={113,114,...,121}
]
\addplot table [y expr=0,meta index=1, header=false] {
114.06 o
119.94 o
};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$L_1=114.06$}] at (axis cs:114.06,0.05) {};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$L_2=119.94$}] at (axis cs:119.94,0.05) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do the ymin and ymax do?

Comment: @soandos >.>, the produced graph has a lower bound of 112.5 and an upper bound of 121.5, let's play "pin the tail on the observable."

Comment: @JeffLangemeier As far as I can tell it *slightly* changes the height of L1 and L2 (tried 10,100,1000 for ymax)

Comment: @soandos, And now I get red on my face, yes, the y bound handles the vertical, but since a line graph has no vertical it doesn't really do squat.  Tired-dyslexia causes y and x confusion tonight, stellar.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier don't sweat it

Comment: What is the function of this snippet?

    {\the\numexpr\x +112\relax}

I get that it is adding 112 to the values of x so that the labels reflect the example I provided, but what is the function of "\the", "\numexpr", and "\relax"?

Comment: @Daniel `\relax` is a nonexpandable TeX primitive that causes TeX to stop scanning (in this case, for a number); `\the` is a TeX primitive that basically "gives the value" of some macros. Comments are too short for a detailed explanation, but you can find it in *TeX by Topic* or in *The TeXbook*.

Comment: @Daniel I forgot to mention `\numexpr`: it is a e-TeX macro for evaluation of numeric expressions.

Comment: This solution is very useful for me as newbie in latex but I have question how can we replace the label with x1, x2,... instead of number. Thank you

Comment: @yant [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question won't be seen by many people here, additionally, comments are not very suitable to place code, so it would be best to repost your question as a fresh one. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 22):

You don't really need any extra packages for that kind of diagram, LaTeX can do that unaided:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{nn}
\setlength\unitlength{2pt}

\begin{picture}(100,100)

\put(10,60){$L_1=114.06$}
\put(70,60){$L_2=119.94$}
\put(50,30){$\mu$}
\put(0,50){\line(1,0){100}}
\multiput(10,50)(10,0){9}{\line(0,1){5}}
\setcounter{nn}{113}%
\multiput(10,40)(10,0){9}{\makebox(0,0){\thenn\stepcounter{nn}}}

\thicklines
\put(20,50){\circle{3}}
\put(80,50){\circle{3}}

\linethickness{2pt}
\put(20,50){\line(1,0){60}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```