# How to make an open circle in a number line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

This is a follow up question to [Labeled Number Line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67991/labeled-number-line)

My question is how can I make an open circle (to indicate an open interval) using Gonzalo Medina's answer.

Comment: Can you explain "open circle" please?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this sort of "open circle".http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq8Ii.png It is used to denote an open interval.

Comment: Gonzalo has two answers there. Which answer you would like to be modified?

Comment: The second one would help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis y line=none,
  axis lines=left,
  axis line style={-},
  xmin=112.5,
  xmax=121.5,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
  xlabel=$\mu$,
  scatter/classes={
                    a={mark=*,draw=magenta,fill=white},
                    b={mark=*,red}
                    },
  restrict y to domain=0:1,
  xtick={113,114,...,121},
  point meta=explicit symbolic,
]
\addplot[scatter,blue,thick] table [y expr=0,meta index=1, header=false] {
114.06 a
119.94 b
};

\node[coordinate,label=above:{$L_1=114.06$}] at (axis cs:114.06,0.05) {};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$L_2=119.94$}] at (axis cs:119.94,0.05) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

And a fairly general [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) solution...

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

% open or closed ends?
boolean a_open, b_open;
a_open = true;
b_open = false;

% lower and upper values
a = 114.06;
b = 119.94;

% color for the interval
color interval_color;
interval_color = .47 red;

% limits for tick marks
alpha = floor(a)-1;
omega = ceiling(b)+1;

% horizontal & vertical units
u = 8cm/(omega-alpha);
v = 1cm;

% axis
drawarrow (-5mm,0) -- ((omega-alpha)*u+5mm,0) withcolor .3 white;
% with ticks and labels
for i=0 step ceiling(8mm/u) until omega-alpha:
  draw (origin -- (0,v/5)) shifted (i*u,0) withcolor .3 white;
  label(decimal (alpha+i), (i*u,-v/2));
  endfor

% lower and upper points on the line
z1 = ((a-alpha)*u,0);
z2 = ((b-alpha)*u,0);

% draw the interval
draw z1--z2 withpen pencircle scaled 1.6 withcolor interval_color;

% mark the ends
fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted z1 withcolor interval_color;
if a_open: fill fullcircle scaled 3 shifted z1 withcolor background; fi

fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted z2 withcolor interval_color;
if b_open: fill fullcircle scaled 3 shifted z2 withcolor background; fi

% labels (done like this to use the values already given for a and b)
write "label(btex $L_1=" & decimal a & "$ etex,z1+(0,2/3v));" to ".mplabels"; 
write "label(btex $L_2=" & decimal b & "$ etex,z2+(0,2/3v));" to ".mplabels"; 
write EOF to ".mplabels";
input .mplabels;

label(btex $\mu$ etex, .5[z1,z2]-(0,6/5v));

endfig;
end.
```

This should work fairly automatically for different lower and upper bounds, for example just by changing these lines

```
% open or closed ends?
a_open = false;
b_open = true;

% lower and upper values
a = 57.2;
b = 73.1;
```

you get

[image]

If you had lots of them to draw, you could make a `vardef`-like function for them.

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\def\beginning{113}
\def\first{114.06 }  %  left side of interval
\def\second{119.94 } % right side of interval
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.55)(8.5,0.5)
  \pnodes{P}%
    (!\first \beginning sub 0)%
    (!\second \beginning sub 0)
  \psaxes[yAxis = false, Ox = \beginning]{->}(0,0)(-0.5,0)(8.5,0)
  \psline[linewidth = 1.5pt, linecolor = blue](P0)(P1)
  \psdot[dotstyle = Bo](P0)
  \uput[90](P0){$L_{1} = \first$}
  \psdot(P1)
  \uput[90](P1){$L_{2} = \second$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]