# How to plot time intervals?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

This is not a `LaTex` question but might be relevant to people in here. Does anyone know how can I plot time intervals. I am interested to plot some thing like this but I don't know how. I prefer to use `gnuplot` if it can do the job:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that, as you indicated yourself, this is not on-topic for this site. (Cheap spaghetti may be relevant to people here but it doesn't make it on-topic.) You could ask this kind of thing in chat, but unless you can revise it to have something to do with TeX or friends (needn't be LaTeX, of course), it does not belong on the main site...

Comment: Might be relevant to people in here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45006/how-to-plot-intervals-and-points-in-the-real-line

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684475/plotting-labeled-intervals-in-matplotlib-gnuplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Gantt Chart. See GnuPlot example at

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/gantt.html

Comment: Thanks, I found gantt.py is also useful for this. http://wiki.mn.wtb.tue.nl/wonham/gantt.py